# What is proper or effective way for Composition of React Component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have multiple view in my application, I need helpl in how to use reusable component effectively ? Is it ohk if I create viewspecific component from reusable component ?  - Generic Tree View . For users View   which will render  with user specific data and actions .

I have written re useable component in my react app.Which I have to use it with different data and action is it ohk to creat new component which use resuable component and provide data related to that ?

i.e

Component - DepartmentTree which renders  and some functions related to Department. So finaly I will render

Component - usersTree same way here it calls  and methods related to users . In the users view I will render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely OK to create a view-specific component that renders a reusable component. You could let this depend on how big your page is. If it includes a lot of components, then do split them up in view specific components.

About the data, you have a few options... First of all you could map the data response to a general structure that your TreeView component can read, so you only need to pass some props to the TreeView component. You could do this in the redux reducer.

If you require specific data different behaviour, but you still want to use the reusable TreeView component, you could think about creating a Higher Order Component. This component will wrap your reusable component and add some specific logic to it. You can read about it and see some good examples here: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

The most important thing I always keep in mind: It's not always about how you finally do it, it's about keeping it simple, understandable and consistent.